# How to select a repeating pattern of non-adjacent cells in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: charts, microsoft-excel-365

I have an MS Excel spreadsheet having 603 records, each record having 27 rows and 4 columns for a total of 16,281 rows. My task is to create a line chart of the data (shock number from 1 to 603) in Column A from cells A3, then A30, then A57 and so on to cell A16256, and its related shock value in cells D13, D40, D67 and so on to cell D16266
Using the mouse to select each of these cells while holding down the Ctrl key does not seem like the smart way to do this.
My original idea was to move the values to respective columns having adjacent cells, but have no objection to generating the line chart from this selection, as is if possible.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. Can you add a little sample data to the question so we can better help you?

Comment: Of course. I attempted tp paste 3 records, but it was over 1,000 characters too many. How about a link? Look for test_11_21_23.xlsx https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvbRThajlgqAlVW5kEb3zV3dcagc?e=dcXs25

Comment: You need to create more columns. Restructure the data.

Comment: @Toni, yes, I've started another column off to the side having header "sn" with a series from 1 to 603 beneath with which I had planned to use to restructure the data. Thanks.

Comment: @Toni, and also 2 columns for Upstream Bz and Downstream Bz.

Comment: @FlexYourData don't let the spreadsheet worry you. I'm a self-taught hobbyist Python enthusiast who accepted the challenge of using Python to read the Interplanetary Shock cdf put out by Goddard Space Flight Center and generate a line chart of Bz values.

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you'd like to structure the data to directly support your chart.  However, since this appears to be a consistent output format from a different source, you can just use the Excel [OFFSET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) function to gather the data you want included in your chart.

For a quick and easy solution, you'll want to choose a reference point (e.g. $A$1) to anchor the calculations.  Then create a table with the following columns:

Assuming the table starts in F1
**Offset** {2,29,56...} F2 =2, F3 = F2+27 and fill down 600 rows.
**SN** =OFFSET($A$1,F2,0) this finds $A$1, counts down the appropriate number of rows from the offset column then fills the SN value there.
**Bz** =OFFSET($A$1,F2+10,3) this finds $A$1, counts down the appropriate number of rows from the offset column and then 10 more, then counts over 3 columns and fills the Bz value there.

[image: formulas]

[image: values]

Then use these table values for your chart.  You can add additional columns for Bx and By (or any other value) as necessary, including creating XY/Scatter charts if you like.

One note, somewhere around the 10505 row mark, your data left out one separator line (---) and as a result the values below that are off.  It'll be easy to find since the SN value will change to "spacecraft".  You'll need to add an additional row there for the table to be completely accurate.  Also, you'll want to watch future copies to make sure the output structure remains consistent.